# Why is this LR(1) grammar not LALR(1)?

Tags: parsing, grammar, lalr, lr-grammar

This is not my homework, I'm trying to understand LALR(1) grammars. So I found [this](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/03-11-026)

```
S -> aEa | bEb | aFb | bFa
E -> e
F -> e
```

I wrote the LR items, but I can't figure out
why this is an LR(1) grammar and not LALR(1)?

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's begin by constructing LR(1) configurating sets for the grammar:

```
 (1)
 S' -> .S [$]
 S  -> .aEa [$]
 S  -> .aFb [$]
 S  -> .bFa [$]
 S  -> .bEb [$]

 (2)
 S' -> S. [$]

 (3)
 S  -> a.Ea [$]
 S  -> a.Fb [$]
 E  -> .e   [a]
 F  -> .e   [b]

 (4)
 E  -> e.   [a]
 F  -> e.   [b]

 (5)
 S  -> aE.a [$]

 (6)
 S  -> aEa. [$]

 (7)
 S  -> aF.b [$]

 (8)
 S  -> aFb. [$]

 (9)
 S  -> b.Fa [$]
 S  -> b.Eb [$]
 E  -> .e   [b]
 F  -> .e   [a]

 (10)
 E  -> e.   [b]
 F  -> e.   [a]

 (11)
 S  -> bF.a [$]

 (12)
 S  -> bFa. [$]

 (13)
 S  -> bE.b [$]

 (14)
 S  -> bEb. [$]
```

If you'll notice, states (4) and (10) have the same core, so in the LALR(1) automaton we'd merge them together to form the new state

```
 (4, 10)
 E -> e. [a, b]
 F -> e. [a, b]
```

Which now has a reduce/reduce conflict in it (all conflicts in LALR(1) that weren't present in the LR(1) parser are reduce/reduce, by the way).  This accounts for why the grammar is LR(1) but not LALR(1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: well, you helped me a lot, I realised one mistake a do in an analysis in my pdf, but anyway, I found this [here](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/95-02-053) and I wanted to prove it to my self, my result is also that it's a valid LARL(1) grammar, so I guess there is a mistake on that website? am I right?

Comment: I guess that would be a mistake on the website, since we just built the LALR automaton and had `bison` check it for us.  I would assume that the intent was to find a LALR but not SLR grammar.

Comment: well, I figured it out, you miss rules E->e and F->e in your analysis, that's why `bison` didn't have any error output

Comment: @Jan Vorcak- Can you explain this in more detail?  I definitely factored in these rules (I assume that e means 'epsilon;' is this incorrect?)

Comment: well, I knew I didn't get something about your analysis, e is a terminal symbol as you can see on the source website, if it's an epsilon, it would be pretty simple grammar, I noticed that in many cases they mark epsilon as lambda character

Comment: @JanVorcak- Answer updated.  Can you take a look at this and see if it explains things better?

Comment: Thank u it helped a lot but the state S0 is wrong (It is S->bEb not S->bFb)

Comment: Is there a typo in the second line of state 10? It reads `E  -> e.   [a]`, I think it should be `F  -> e.   [a]`